# calculate number of days between dates

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to calculate the number of dates between dates in my table

I have two columns named DateStarted & DateReturned

I need to calculate the number of days between ALL of the records

This is what I have

```
=DateDiff("d",Date(),[DueDate])
```

But how do I get it to do this for every single record and tell me the total number of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query based on your table that calculates the difference:

```
SELECT  DateStarted, 
        DateReturned, 
        DateDiff("d",DateStarted,DateReturned) As NumberOfDays
FROM    Table1
```

This will return a table something like:

[image: Initial table, Query & Results]

Comment: That worked wonders - Thank you. Is there a quick way to add up all the lost days together?

Comment: To add all the numbers together and display it in the same table you could use: `SELECT DateStarted, DateReturned, DateDiff("d",DateStarted,DateReturned) As NumberOfDays, (SELECT SUM (DateDiff("d",DateStarted,DateReturned)) FROM Table1) AS TotalDays FROM Table1`.  Using the example in my post this would give you a fourth column with 32 in each record (4+32-4).